# How to round of 0.5 in sql-server?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

How to round of 0.5 in sql-server?
Sample input : `16.65`

Comment: Sample Input and OutPut

[16.65  --->  17]
[16.07  --->  16.5]

Comment: query please...

Comment: one coffee for me!

Comment: Read this https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/round-transact-sql

Comment: @JoeTaras You will give query then I will give coffee to you...

Comment: Thanks, friends I got it......

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this

```
DECLARE @val DECIMAL(8,2) = 16.65
SELECT CAST(CEILING((@val)*2)/2 AS DECIMAL(8,1))
```

output: `17.0`

```
DECLARE @val DECIMAL(8,2) = 16.07
SELECT CAST(CEILING((@val)*2)/2 AS DECIMAL(8,1))
```

output: `16.5`

Comment: Thanks @Cool_Br33ze. It's working fine. Once's again thanks

Comment: I tried to upvote it says less than 15 reputations @Cool_Br33ze.

Comment: @rajeshkumar Not to worry, thanks for the accepted answer

Answer (score 0):

You have to add `0.5` to Your number and use `FLOOR` function on that added sum.

For Example:

```
declare @number decimal(4,2)
set @number = 16.65

select  FLOOR(@number + 0.5)
```

Comment: Thanks, @whencesoever. Sample Input and OutPut [16.65 ---> 17] [16.07 ---> 16.5] First sample input is working fine but second sample input not working.

Comment: @rajeshkumar that's true. Working on better answer :D.

Comment: Thanks @Whencesoever

Answer (score 0):

I tried below query.

```
DECLARE @Val FLOAT;SET @Val = 16.65
SELECT
    CASE
        WHEN (ROUND(@Val / 10,1) * 10)>@Val
        THEN ROUND(@Val / 10,1) * 10
        ELSE (ROUND(@Val / 10,1) * 10) + 0.5
    END
```